# Set default value of field to auto_increment value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, default-value

I have a table where I have an auto increment column `id` and another column `ord`.

My goal is to have a 'default' value for `ord` that is `id`. I am using a trigger (see below), but it always uses `0` instead of the `id` value.

When I remove the auto_increment from `id`, it works as it should. *How can I set the 'default' value of a field to the one of an auto_increment field?*

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ord` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ord_ai` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
 FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.ord IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.ord := NEW.id;
END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of the id field from `INFORMATION_SCHMEA.TABLES` and use it for  `ord` field.

```
delimiter //

drop trigger if exists ord_ai //

CREATE TRIGGER `ord_ai` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.ord IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.ord := ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
                        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() );
  END IF;
END;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly fine. But why is `id` zero in my code? Also, why doesn't `LAST_INSERT_ID()` work?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works only after insertion is complete. It is not available in `before insert` trigger.