# How to get currently inserted AUTO_INCREMENT id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table structure.

[image]

I want to insert the same value for `item_image_name` as the value of `item_id`(this is AUTO_INCREMENT) at the time of inserting a new record.

**EDIT**
I want this at the time of insertion

```
INSERT INTO items(user_id, item_image_name) VALUES ('','LAST_INCREMENT_VALUE + 1')
```

Comment: first insert then get last inserted id and update value of `item_image_name`

Comment: See this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: You can't get the next id without doing an insert. If you only check what the next id will be there is a risk that something else get inserted before you insert.

Comment: @AwladLiton I know this approach.. I was just wondering that can I get in single INSERT statement at the time of inserting ..

INSERT INTO items(user_id, item_image_name) VALUES ('','LAST_INCREMENT_VALUE + 1')

Comment: @WizKid Your comment is the answer to my question.. :P

Comment: But to be honest I have no idea why you have the item_image_name if it is always id. Just delete the field instead.

Comment: @WizKid: Yes. But that column becomes useful when a related image file is stored with its primary name as `item_id` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by defining a `before insert` trigger on the table.
In the body, first you can find next auto increment value to be assigned to primary key field and use the same for `image_name` field.

**Example**:

```
delimiter //

drop trigger if exists bi_on_items //

create trigger bi_on_items before insert on items
for each row
begin
  if NEW.item_image_name is null OR length( trim( NEW.item_image_name ) ) = 0 then
    set NEW.item_image_name := ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                                  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'items'
                                    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() );

  end if;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Seems a very good solution ... But sad is I cannot understand this.. I am new to MySQL triggers :(

Comment: You can ask to get clarified.

Comment: Before that, also look into [a similar posting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23083718/767881) on which I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_insert_id() to get the last inserted id on the current connection.

Comment: I know, but read my question again ... I am asking something diff

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_insert_id` — Get the ID generated in the last query

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$sid=mysql_insert_id();
```

I you insert the first row the  `$sid` should be 1

To insert next use `$sid+1`

**Edit**

**For your question:** write a query to get the last `item_id` and use that `id + 1` to fill the current `item_image_name`.

**Note:** for the new item `item_id`  and `item_image_name` should same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

This should be used instead of mysql_insert_id() since on PHP 5.5 native MySQL driver has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. The auto increment ID is generated only upon successful insert. So you won't have access to it *during* the insert process.

The alternative would be to make an insert first and then get the last id by using `mysql_insert_id()` and then update the same row using the retrieved id.

PS: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions as are officially deprecated post v5.5. Switch to PDO or mysqli as soon as you can.

Comment: Yes I have used this approeach, first inserted, then got the LAS_INSERT_ID and then updated the same row to enter value for ITEM_IMAGE_NAME..

I was just thinking is there any MySQL function that can get last increment in that table of the PRIMARY_KEY

Comment: As I said, you can't know the value of the auto increment column during or before the insert process

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

first insert then get last inserted id and update value of item_image_name

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$query = "your insert query";// insert with all fields and set item_image_name to empty


 if( $mysqli->query($query)){

    $id= $mysqli->insert_id;
    $query = "UPDATE your_table set item_image_name= '$id' where item_id = $id LIMIT 1 ";//now update the value of item_image_name
    $mysqli->query($query);
    }
```

USE `MYSQLI_*` or `PDO` do not use `mysql_*` since `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE  'tablename'` to get the next auto incremented id.

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$nextId = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

and then use the variable $nextId in your insert query

```
INSERT INTO items(user_id, item_image_name) VALUES ('',$nextId)
```

Comment: Check WizKid's comment when using this approach

Answer (score 0):

What mysql driver are you using?

If you are using mysql driver then you will get the last inserted id with `mysql_insert_id();`

for PDO driver: `PDO::lastInsertId();`

Note: mysql driver is deprecated from PHP 5.5 (http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Comment: Not what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

Get last inserted id first.

```
select item_id as lastId from items order by id desc limit 0,1
```

Now use lastId in your query.

```
INSERT INTO items(user_id, item_image_name) VALUES ('','lastId+1')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an insert into select query

```
INSERT INTO items(user_id, item_image_name) VALUES ('','SELECT MAX(item_id)+1 FROM items')
```